# How to cURL loop and download all the pages

Tags: shell, api, csv, curl, pagination

I'm trying to cURL an API and able to get the data, and when I've checked through the API I was only able to get 1 page of data out of 30 pages. I'm using the command as

Command used:

```
curl --insecure --header '-token-' -H "Accept: application/csv" -H "Content-Type: application/csv" https://example/api/views/ > data.csv
```

I tried the pages command as:

```
curl --insecure --header '-token-' -H "Accept: application/csv" -H "Content-Type: application/csv" https://example/api/views?PageIndex=2&PageSize=30 > data_all_pages.csv
```

How could we able to execute it through shell? For pagination or call the cURL command by running one time.

Comment: You'll have to go beyond cURL, writing a bash script – or using another language – to achieve that. Take a look at this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html. Also, if you'd like to create a single CSV containing the results from all pages, it's a better idea using `>>` instead of `>` to append the output to the `data_all_pages.csv` file.

Comment: Ok do can you share any code for the loop?

Comment: Have you seen the link I sent in my previous comment? There are some examples there on how to make a loop. If you tried some code but even with that couldn't achieve what you want, please update your question to add your attempt.